# sed works when input from echo but not from file

Tags: linux, shell, sed, osx, regular-expression

The following removes the surrounding quotes of the email address string:

```
$ echo  "john.doe@gmail.com" | sed 's/"([^"]*)"/\0/g'  
john.doe@gmail.com
```

But if:

```
$ cat ~/Desktop/emails.txt 
"john.doe@gmail.com"  
$ sed 's/"([^"]*)"/\0/g' ~/Desktop/emails.txt    
"john.doe@gmail.com"   
$ sed -i '' 's/"([^"]*)"/\0/g' ~/Desktop/emails.txt
$ cat ~/Desktop/emails.txt 
"john.doe@gmail.com"
```

Trying to apply the exact same sed regex substitution using a file containing the same string does not work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ah it is unquoted because echo takes the whole string without quotes. But why are quotes added then in the file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am sorry but your `echo` example does not work. It seems to work because double quote (`"`) are interpreted by `bash` and never passed to `sed`.

Note the difference between the following two examples:

```
$ echo "john.doe@gmail.com" 
john.doe@gmail.com
$ echo "\"john.doe@gmail.com\"" 
"john.doe@gmail.com"
```

Your `echo` command does not feed the `"` to `sed` so it seems to work because there are no `"` to remove in input string.

If you try correctly escaping the `"`, the `echo` example will do not work as the `file` example:

```
$ echo  "\"john.doe@gmail.com\"" | sed 's/"([^"]*)"/\0/g'  
"john.doe@gmail.com"
```

You `sed` command has two errors:

1. You are using the extended regex syntax. You can use it only if you have `gnu` sed. The difference is in the way they use the parenthesis.
2. You must count back-references starting by `1`.

So the correct command is:

```
echo  "\"john.doe@gmail.com\"" | sed 's/"\([^"]*\)"/\1/g'
```

or, if your `sed` supports extended regex:

```
echo "\"john.doe@gmail.com\"" | sed -E 's/"([^"]*)"/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
gv@debian:$ cat a.txt
"john.doe@gmail.com"

gv@debian:$ sed 's#"##g' a.txt #remove all quotes
john.doe@gmail.com

gv@debian:$ cat a.txt |tr -d '"' #remove all quotes
john.doe@gmail.com

gv@debian:$ sed 's#^"##g; s#"$##g' a.txt #remove first and last quote 
john.doe@gmail.com

gv@debian:$ a="\"john.doe@gmail.com\"";echo -e "$a" "\n" "${a: 1:-1}" #remove first and last char
"john.doe@gmail.com" 
 john.doe@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @andcoz, this

```
$ sed -i '' 's/"([^"]*)"/\0/g' ~/Desktop/emails.txt
```

needs the `parentheses` escaped and the `backreference` changed from `\0` to `\1`.

After modification, a functional `sed` command looks like this:

```
$ sed -i '' 's/"\([^"]*\)"/\1/g' ~/Desktop/emails.txt
```